# How do I create the installer or executable for .NET framework and .NET core in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I've been a Microsoft stack developer since 1996.  What I'm used to is just running a build in Visual Studio in release mode and finding the executable (and supporting files) in a sub-directory.  I could then just put that somewhere on my computer, create a shortcut, and I could use my little utility tools without issue.

Then came .NET Core and newer versions of Windows that don't like running executables that weren't specifically installed.  I missed the transition, partly because my work experience when the shift happened didn't use the new stuff (companies I worked for just kept using their old stuff) and because the past couple years have been in the Unix/Linux stack.  But, I'd like to be able to write my little practice tools again (like a multiple file rename tool that is more robust than what's available for organizing family photo albums).

I've tried looking for tutorials and advice, but the search terms for ".NET", "framework", "core", "install", and so on all lead to things about installing those frameworks on the computer... not what to do with code I've written in Visual Studio.  I looked for questions here on StackOverflow too.  I'm failing at finding what I'm looking for.

I'm asking for help finding the resources that explain the new model of creating the finished product in Visual Studio (I'm using 2019 currently).  Or if it's simple and I'm just missing something that can be explained quickly, having the explanation here would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "don't like running executables that weren't specifically installed" mean? I create small apps all the time and run them fine after moving the exe and dependencies where I need them. Are you writing a CLI, Windows Form, or some other UI?

Comment: @Kit, When I try running executables outside of VS, Windows pops up a window asking me if I really want to run the executable because it's not a registered program.

Comment: Ya, I don't get that. It really sounds like a problem with your OS configuration somehow. You may want to ask your question on Super User.

Comment: Fair enough on the Super User suggestion.  But I'm still not sure what to do with .NET Core.  It seems to have drastically changed what happens and doesn't seem to create an executable.  Something about the MSIL and you still have to go some extra steps.  Is there a resource that explains what you're supposed to do in Core to get your program?